# How do I make the value binding of NSTokenField supply an NSString?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding

I have replaced an `NSTextField` with an `NSTokenField` so that I can perform some auto-completion. The value of the `NSTextField` was bound to a `NSString` attribute of a  controller class. Now that I have changed the `NSTextField` to an `NSTokenField` the value has changed to an `NSArray`.

How do I make the `NSTokenField` value binding be an `NSString`?

The changing of the value from an `NSString` to an `NSArray` seems like bad OO design. I though that a subclass should be able replace a superclass without any modifications to the subclass.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is autocompletion, and not tokenization, you can achieve this by using a plain NSTextField and implementing the delegate method:

```
- (NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index
```

(This method is actually declared in NSControl, NSTextField's superclass.)

If you do want to have tokenization, then you will have to provide an NSArray for the object value to be displayed in the token field.  As explained in [the NSTokenField programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/TokenFieldArchitecture/TokenFieldArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH4-SW4), the array you provide will be a mix of strings and objects.  Strings will be displayed as-is, and any non-string objects will be displayed as tokens in the token field.  You would need to implement the various NSTokenField delegate methods to provide a string to be displayed for each represented object in your array.

It does appear that the [Cocoa Bindings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTokenField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTokenField-DontLinkElementID_697) states that the object bound to the value of an NSTokenField should be a string or number, but in my experience, this is incorrect, and the token field should be bound to an NSArray, just like when using setObjectValue:

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass your own [NSValueTransformer](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and set it in your binding.

Answer (score 1):

NSTokenField's value binding accepts an NSString or NSNumber binding, not an NSArray. How have you determined that it is wanting an NSArray?

Comment: I believe the documentation is wrong: [my Radar on the issue](http://openradar.appspot.com/11226270).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (as Cocoafan pointed out) is to use [Value Transformers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/TransformersRole.html).  Value transformers allow you convert the object-type used your model into a type that's suitable for a view.  Here is a very simple String/Array transformer that allows you to store your data as a comma separated string but will convert it back and forth to an array of strings.

```
@interface StringArrayTransformer: NSValueTransformer {}
@end

@implementation StringArrayTransformer

+ (Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSString class]; }

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return YES; }

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    NSString *string = (NSString*) value;
    return [string componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
}

-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    NSArray *array = (NSArray*)value;
    return [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
}
@end
```

If you're using bindings for your NSTokenField then to use this the transformer simply select the NSTokenField in Interface Builder, then in the Bindings Inspector on the right hand side, for the Value binding, set the "Value Transformer" to `StringArrayTransformer` as per below.

[image: Setting the Value Transformer Binding for NSTokenField]